# Spring MVC 5.*: Wizard Forms validation with Validator

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am creating a multipage forms application. I'd like to use Validator interface to validate the content provided by the user.

The question: Is this https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/ approach still valid in terms of Spring MVC 5.2.*?

Ofc, we should forget about AbstractWizardFormController for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And answering on my own question:
You do not have to do it. Normally validator will catch errors before the page was switched. Basically, one needs to implement validator as told here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validator. Then bind it to the controller with

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(<validaotrs_variable_name>);
    }
```

And then use @Validated on @ModelAttribute("myobjectnameintemplate") MyPojo myPojo.

That is it.

If the one wants to validate page at a time, then I think it is necessary to run validation methods separately. For this I found a number of answers on stackoverflow:

1. One can use @Valid and validation groups (Hibernate)
2. Simple switch case in validate() based on the current page or something else
3. Nested objects in one object that is being populated, and multiple validators as described here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validator